# How can I create development and production settings files in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, app-config, slowcheetah

Does Visual Studio (or any extension) offer a way to achieve the equivalent of a configuration transform at the `.settings` file level? I know that there are tools such as SlowCheetah for creating transformations on the `app.config`, and I suppose the contents of the `.settings` file get written to the `app.config` eventually, but what I'd like to do is have two settings files, such as:

- `settings.debug.settings`
- `settings.release.settings`

Then, ideally the same code (below) could be used to extract `FooSetting` from either `.settings` file depending on the build configuration.

```
string bar = Properties.Settings.Default.FooSetting;
```

Does anything like this exist or do I need to stick with modifying `app.config` files and creating transformations with SlowCheetah?

Comment: I'm not aware of anything built-in that can do this.